# The meaning of silabbata-paramasa and freedom from this fetter?

Tags: reference-request, abhidhamma, sila

Since often very curious ideas and means of excuses appear around the arguing with the means of "that's a fetter", my person thought it would be good if someone would have the skills and goodness toward fellows and behind followers to explain the meaning and whether a  perception of it is used for the training or not so that it would not misinterpret the Sublime Buddha (meaning own ideas are nice but not really 'asked' for)

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks exchange and other ways of silabbata-paramasa but for release]*

Comment: Is the `abhidhamma` tag (with the `reference-request` tag) meant to mean that any answers should mostly or entirely, only, relevant reference to the Abhidhamma -- quotes from the Abhidhamma?

Comment: Maybe question could be made into two questions: about specifically stated ignorance of being about ritual rather than content; and, if instructors mention meaning as they teach, rather than only presenting ritual

Comment: Sila on the path alwas requires Abhidhamma, good householder Chris.

Answer (score 2):

From [AN 3.78](http://suttacentral.net/an3.78/en/sujato):

> “Take the case of someone who cultivates precepts and observances, a
> lifestyle, and a spiritual path, taking this as the essence. If
> unskillful qualities grow while skillful qualities decline, that’s not
> fruitful. However, if unskillful qualities decline while skillful
> qualities grow, that is fruitful.”

From [MN 24](http://suttacentral.net/mn24/en/sujato):

> “Is the spiritual life lived under the Buddha for the sake of
> purification of ethics?”
>
> “Certainly not.”  ....
>
> “In the same way, reverend, **purification of ethics is only for the
> sake of purification of mind**. Purification of mind is only for the
> sake of purification of view. Purification of view is only for the
> sake of purification through overcoming doubt. Purification through
> overcoming doubt is only for the sake of purification of knowledge and
> vision of the variety of paths. Purification of knowledge and vision
> of the variety of paths is only for the sake of purification of
> knowledge and vision of the practice. Purification of knowledge and
> vision of the practice is only for the sake of purification of
> knowledge and vision. Purification of knowledge and vision is only for
> the sake of extinguishment by not grasping. The spiritual life is
> lived under the Buddha for the sake of extinguishment by not
> grasping.”

From [DN 16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato):

> If it wishes, after my passing the Saṅgha may abolish the lesser and
> minor training rules.

The purpose of the purification of ethics is only for the purification of the mind.

But being too attached to minor rules and rituals to the point that breaking them causes remorse and mental anguish, is unskillful and pollutes the mind.

It is enough to practise purification of ethics with the understanding that it is for the purification of the mind, and not be too attached to following minor rules and rituals to the letter.

Comment: That does not answer the question but seeks for excuse promotion. What's the meaning of? And own ideas are not requested, good householder.